# How to use OneHotEncoder and Pipeline to make new predictions?

Tags: python, pandas, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I'm working through a tutorial focusing on OneHotEncoder. I get the idea behind encoding features, but I'm having a little problem with using the encoder with pipeline to make a new prediction. Two of the features--"Sex" and "Embarked"--are categorical rather than numerical. When creating a new numpy array to make a prediction, do you use the initial values, say "male" and "C", or, say, "1" and "2" to make a new prediction? I get the following error: " ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames," which is weird given that the values I'm using are numerical. Regardless, would I have to fit the pipeline to X_new to make a new prediction? If so, how can I do that?

```
X_new = [[3, 1, 0]] OR X_new = [['3','male', 'C']]

pipe.predict(X_new)
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/---/pandas-videos/master/data/titanic_train.csv")


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')



from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

cross_val_score(logreg, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()


from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)


X = df.drop('Survived', axis='columns')


from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

column_trans = make_column_transformer(

  (OneHotEncoder(), ['Sex', 'Embarked']),

remainder='passthrough')


column_trans.fit_transform(X)


from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

pipe = make_pipeline(column_trans, logreg)



cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()



X_new = [[3, 1, 0]]

pipe.predict(X_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply OneHotEncoder, the categorical column that you specify will be transformed into multiple integer columns based on number of unique value in the categorical column.

For example, the gender column contains 'male' and 'female', then it will converted the original column to 2 columns of 'male' and 'female'. It is difference from the LabelEncoder.

If you want to apply pipeline, logistic regression, and OneHotEncoder, you can use the pipeline to fit with the training data.

```
pipe.fit(X,y)
```

and then you can apply the prediction. This is an example when I apply 3 features as Sex, Age, and embarked and apply OHE to Sex and embarked.

```
X_new = [['female', 20, 'C']]
X_new_df = pd.DataFrame (X_new,columns=['Sex','Age','Embarked'])
pipe.predict(X_new_df)
```

However, the features that you use in your code is all features except label classes ('Survived'), which is 11 features. the number of the input must be equal to or greater than the fitted model, while you apply only 3 columns that may prompt and error.